# Problem when comparing time and text for two cells

Tags: excel

I have 2 Cells that both contain time and text in the field. For these 2 fields, I need to calculate the time difference.
I am struggling with the formula to get it done.

Values that need to be compared are:

"17:00 (next BD)" and "18:00 (previous BD)" - Result should be 01:00

The formula I have so far is: =IFERROR(LEFT(J6,5)-LEFT(F6,5),"N/A")

This is now giving the result ######################

The last push in right direction is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A time cannot be negative and you are probably doing `17:00-18:00`

Comment: Feel like an idiot ;) That's actually it. The first date is previous business day. Will be hard to get 25:00 out of it, right?

Comment: Add `1` when it is the previous day. `=IFERROR((1+LEFT(J6,5))-LEFT(F6,5),"N/A")`

Comment: One of you please create an answer.